# Where to find Drush for Drupal 6?

Tags: drush

I am trying to install and work with Drush for my Drupal 6.22 site. However, [on the modele's page](http://drupal.org/project/drush) I can only find the module's tar.gz package for Drupal 7. nor can I find D6 package elsewhere. So appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drush is version agnostic.  From the same page:

> It is valid to use the latest '7.x' (or master) no matter what your version of Drupal is. Drush is independent of Drupal version :)

Comment: oh my bad! Thanks MPD. Funny enough, drupal site is not available now: The mysqli error was: Too many connections.